# Convert Ruby example to Python

Tags: python, ruby

How would you write that Ruby example in Python?
I am confused by the `'Google Analytics' =>`. My best guess is changing it to :. Is that correct?

```
Analytics.track(
  user_id: '019mr8mf4r',
  event: 'Clicked a Link',
  properties: {
    linkText     : 'Next'
  },
  context: {
    'Google Analytics' => {
        clientId: '1033501218.1368477899'
    }
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: correct.

`=>` is actually the original Hash operator in ruby.
and `:` is a later syntactic sugar of `=>` and symbol `:` combined.

Note that it is not the same between `key: value` and `key : value`,
the former one actually is the same of `:key => value`,
but the latter is `key => value`, i.e. `key` in the second one is a variable.
 `:key` in ruby is a symbol, in many cases can be treated as string `'key'`.

So in your question, you can treat `user_id`, `event`, `properties`, `context`, and `clientId` as strings, but `linkText` is a variable.

And

```
  context: {
    'Google Analytics' => {
        clientId: '1033501218.1368477899'
    }
  }
```

is same as

```
'context' : { 'Google Analytics' : { 'clientId' : '1033501218.1368477899'} }
```

in python.

Comment: Thanks a lot that helped

Comment: Another observation, try don't mix styles of variable or function names like `camelCase` in `clientId` and `snake_case` in `user_id`. Use only one.